# How can I allow the user to style font in NSTextView using interface buttons in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, fonts, styles, nstextview

In short:
I am trying to find information about text styling inside an NSTextView. Bold, italics, indentation, making a word completely uppercase and setting backdrop colors to certain lines.
Any and all info is welcome. I've been looking around the web for docs on the subject and only managed to find a few things that seem to be part of an iphone framework. I'm sure there must be something out there and that I'm just searching for the wrong words.

A few details:
I am not a developer. I am a motion graphics artist and screenwriter. I do know html, php, javascript, css and several scripting languages (all very similar to javascript) used by different graphics apps.

I am not very proficient in objective-c but I've taken up writing a screenwriting app as a bit of a side project. I've been teaching myself objective-c from a book call Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX and using the code I've created from the examples in the book to create my app using Xcode. Styling text was not covered and I am at a loss as to how to approach it.

Screenplays have very specific formats. Using css I could create this format easily so my first thought was to find out if text inside a NSTextview can have css applied to it. I've not found anything that could answer this. Of course I am probably way off with this approach.

Again, any help or anyone who can point me in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks!

-Omar

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because it only accept one style.

You have to deal with UIWebView [Tutorial for this](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) and use your CSS.

Or you can use some code like [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView). I do not test this but I think it will be the easiest way for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I had seen the UIWebView class but all I find seems to suggest it's meant to be used with iOS, not desktop applications. Am I wrong? It seems there are UI and NS classes and that the UI classes are meant for iphone development. The EGOTextView also seems to be meant as a mobile device class. I'm sorry if this is basic, I am fairly new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you're developping for MacOSX. I'm an iOS dev and I can't be sure for this.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying anyway. Hopefully someone will come up with an answer soon.

Comment: Hi everyone, Just dropping by to give some closure to this question in  case someone decides to follow in my footsteps. I found a thread with links to some useful documentation.[Here's the thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1303833).

Comment: Thank ojcruz. You can edit your question to add this link, it'll be more visible.